# Count punctuation in java string

Tags: java

I have a problem where i have to count punctutation in a string. the punctuation i have defined in the array as:

```
char[] arr= {'!','"','#','$','%','&','f','(',')','*','+','-', '.' ,'/' ,':',';','<','=','>','@','[',']', '\', '^', '`' , '{' , '}' , '~'};
```

and the code that counts is :

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
          for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
            if(str.charAt(i) == arr[j]){
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
              pcount++;
            }
          }
          }
```

But here the program is not compiling as it is getting confused in the punctuation as:

> Main.java:10: error: unclosed character literal
> char[] arr= {'!','"','#','$','%','&','f','(',')','*','+','-', '.' ,'/' ,':',';','<','=','>','@','[',']', '', '^', '`' , '{' , '}' ,
> '~'};

Comment: Try double backslash "\\" for slash.

Comment: yes, `'\'` should be `'\\'`. You can even see the highlighting change in the question code as soon as that part is reached.

Answer (score 3):

You have the backslash char in the array. The Backslash char is used in Java for escaping. Use `\\` instead :)

```
char[] arr= {'!','"','#','$','%','&','f','(',')','*','+','-', '.' ,'/' ,':',';','<','=','>','@','[',']', '\\', '^', '`' , '{' , '}' , '~'};
```

Answer (score 3):

A backslash is an *escape character*. That means that the character immediately succeeding the backslash is interpreted in a special way. Those two together are called an *escape sequence*.

For instance, to write a literal `'` within a character literal, you must escape the `'`, because otherwise the quote will be interpreted as the ending delimiter of the character literal. That's wy it must be escaped using a backslash (`\'`). The same holds for a backslash itself — it must be escaped.

Let's break down what happens to your backslash character `'\'`:

```
'   ⟶ Denotes that this is the start of a character literal.
\   ⟶ Backslash means that the immediately succeeding character is 'escaped',
        it is given a special meaning by the compiler.
'   ⟶ This character is given a special meaning by the compiler, because of the
        preceding backslash character. In this case, the backslash and the
        single quote together are interpreted as a literal single quote
        character.
```

Because the previous character was part of an escape sequence, there is no
closing single quote left. So you have a syntax error.

So `'\'` should be `'\\'`.

See also chapter [*Characters*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) Of the Oracle Java Tutorials.